# Showing "New Opportunity" option in Salesforce for Outlook side bar

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

In Outlook side panel currently there is an option for creating contact (See attachment - I have configured "Salesforce for outlook"). Is there any way to add option for creating "Opportunities" as well.

Kindly help.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_side_panel_set_up_publisher.htm&language=en_US

Your Salesforce edition determines which side panel features your reps can access and how you set up reps to use the side panel publisher.

1. Verify that you’ve set up Create a Record global quick actions for each action you want to be available in your reps’ side panel publisher menus.
2. Add the actions to the appropriate publisher layout.

   - For Contact Manager or Group Editions, add global quick actions to
     your reps’ side panel publisher menus with the global publisher
     layout editor. Any global quick actions you add to the side panel are
     displayed for all features you’ve configured that leverage global
     quick actions. The side panel publisher, however, displays only
     actions with the action type Create a Record.
   - For Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, or Developer
     Editions, add global quick actions to your reps’ side panel publisher
     menus with the side panel publisher layout editor. You can create
     multiple side panel publisher layouts to give different reps access
     to different side panel publisher menus.
3. Assign side panel publisher layouts to your reps.
   For Contact Manager or Group Editions, assign your global publisher layout to user profiles to give reps access.
   For Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, or Developer Editions, assign your side panel publisher layout to user profiles to give reps access.